# What's a good microphone for movie making?

Tags: microphone

What's a good microphone for movie making with a DSLR? I'm going to use it both indoors and outdoors. It has to be stereo.. I can use both a boom microphone and a hot shoe microphone.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of qualities are you looking for? I imagine the majority of the microphone market is 'good' for at least some specific application.

Comment: I need the actors voices to be nice and clear. If it is possible I need it to capture everything good. But if it isn't we can record all the other sounds like the sound of a cup being placed on a table and mix them in afterwards.

Comment: We are going to make feature films in all types of genres.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I'm looking for something below $250 if this doesn't compromise the sound much.

Comment: We want to keep this from being a [shopping recommendation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) so focus on what kinds of microphones suit these tasks, rather than which specific models match a certain pricepoint.

Comment: Question doesn't mention much to narrow it down. Locations? Budget? How will the audio be processed? Vote to close as vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For DSLR film making you can't go wrong with a Sennheiser ME66 into a Zoom H4N.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I'm looking for something below $250 if this doesn't compromise the sound much.

Comment: So, you recommend both of them? Which one is the best if I'm only going to buy one?

Comment: This is a mic and recorder combo which wil set you back about $1000, so out of your price range. Making "feature" films with a $250 audio budget isn't really reasonable. You might be able to find a AT 875 short shotgun and a Tascam DR40 for less than $400.

Comment: Why is the ME66 the go-to mic? Is it kind of like the Shure SM57 in audio, in that it's something of a known robust standard?

Comment: Ok. Hmm. So what's the microphones you would recommend if I'm going to spend as little money as possible? I'm going to buy a D7000 and lenses for $2000. So the video and audio quality should be somewhat equal..

Comment: Hmm, so what's the Tascam DR40 and the Zoom H4N? What's the benefit of not using the jack-input in the camera? We have plenty of XLR stage mics (Shure SM58) available and condenser mics XLR (Shure SM57)(mainly for micing guitar monitors) and condenser mics used as overheads for a drum kit. (I can find what it's called if it could be used. Is that a good idea to use, or would it give poor feature film quality compared to your suggestions?

Comment: Yes, ME66 is very much a proven standard. I'd say as respected in the documentary crowd as a 57 or 58 to the audio crowd. The on camera audio is horrible. Only use it for sync reference to a better audio source. Not just my opinion, but standard practice for DSLR shooting. Sure, you can plut a RODE mic into your camera and get something usable, but if you are investing $2,000 in the look, then $400 - $1000 for the sound seems reasonable. If you are in a quiet environment, you may be able to get away with the drum condensor. Normally I'm in noisy locations and need the shotgun.

Comment: Thanks! So I've upped my budget to $1000, but I'm hoping to get it around $800. (If you use £ or € tell me, because I'm converting from Norwegian Kroners anyway..) If I spend $850 on audio gear then I'll end up with $4680.. I have to buy everything new because now I have a D40 ($400) with two lenses 18-55,55-200 worth $200..

Comment: What's your final recommendation? I have no experience with audio in the film industry, so I don't have any experience to decide myself..

Comment: I'd say get the ME66 and it could last you decades. The audio recorder will get replaced in a few years probably. If you want to save money, get the Tascam DR 40. I love mine, although it is not quite as robust as the Zoom H4N. So, the Senny ME66 and Tascam DR40 should set you back $700. Add $200 if you want the Tascam. It won't  change the sound quality, but it might end up lasting longer if you abuse your equipment. And lets face it, who doesn't.

Comment: Is this a microphone that only picks up what's in front of it, and not from the sides? So you point it at the one who speaks?

Comment: Hi again! I've found the ME66 microphone module. Do you need the power module to use it if you use it with the Zoom H4N? I mean, is the power module only of you don't have phantom power? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, get the power module... using phantom on the recorder tends to run the batteries down quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Just doing some research for a friend and ran across this thread. It may be a bit late to throw in a couple of cents, but in my experience you will want to try to keep your dialog as separate as possible from the other sounds. The ME66 will certainly do the trick, provided you have a good boom operator, but if you are hoping to capture other sounds you should strive for as much isolation as possible and get those other audio events on a different channel. This will give you a lot more control in post. The dialog itself should always be recorded on a single mono channel, no stereo needed. Hope you have found the process fun and rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing a little research on the Zoom H4N, and it appears that you can get really good quality from the [Tascam DR40](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NACC6M), and it's $160 vs. the ~$300 price of the Zoom. Regarding shotgun mics, based on your budget you're going to have to settle for something sub par. Though from what I've read you "can" get away with just using the Zoom or Tascam device by itself, again it may not be optimal for what you want, but it's a great way to do it on a small budget.

Comment: I bought the Zoom H4n with a Sennheiser ME66.

Comment: How is it working out for you? Any chance you have some clips with the sound at this point?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any real-world clips yet. We are still planning the manuscript...